# How to add class to parent elements?

Tags: jquery, class, parent

For the span element with the class "arrows", I'm trying to add a class to the div with the class "collapse" from its parents and also an attribute to the div with the class "navbar-toggler".

I tried the following code:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.arrows[aria-expanded="true"]').closest('.navbar-toggler').setAttribute("aria-expanded", true);
});

$(function() {
  $('.arrows[aria-expanded="true"]').parents('.collapse').addClass('in')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="navbar-toggler collapse-icons" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#exCollapsingNavbar10">
  <i class="material-icons add"></i>
  <i class="material-icons remove"></i>
</div>

<div class="collapse" id="exCollapsingNavbar10">
  <ul class="category-sub-menu">
    <li data-depth="1" data-id="11">
      <a class="category-sub-link" href=" ">Educație Arduino</a>
      <span class="arrows" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#exCollapsingNavbar11" aria-expanded="true">
```

Comment: You miss the reference on which to target. If there are multiple ones, you need to refer to this (as in the element clicked) and then move the way up.

Comment: Did you see the error in the console? `setAttribute()` is a native JavaScript method. You can't invoke it on a jQuery object. Use `attr()`.

Comment: Note that you don't need multiple `ready()` functions. Put all your code in one.

Comment: I had no errors in console, but I'll keep that in mind, thank you! I'm new to this and still learning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('.arrows[aria-expanded=true]')
  .parents('.collapse')
  .addClass('in')
  .prev()
  .attr('aria-expanded', true);
```

```css
.in {
  background: yellow;
}

.navbar-toggler[aria-expanded=true] {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="navbar-toggler collapse-icons" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#exCollapsingNavbar10">
  <i class="material-icons add"></i>
  <i class="material-icons remove"></i>
</div>

<div class="collapse" id="exCollapsingNavbar10">
  <ul class="category-sub-menu">
    <li data-depth="1" data-id="11">
      <a class="category-sub-link" href=" ">Educație Arduino</a>
      <span class="arrows" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#exCollapsingNavbar11" aria-expanded="true"></span
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```